# Avoid Nested Function, Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging

New to JavaScript so i appreciate your patience...i'm looking to write a Google Cloud Function that will send a message upon a DB entry.  It has to get the data from multiple locations within the DB. Below is what i have so far:

```
exports.NotifyNewApplication = functions.database
    .ref(`/Applications/{applicationId}/appWith`)
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        var applicationId = context.params.applicationId; 
        console.log('status',  applicationId); 
        var recieverId = snapshot.val();
        var database = admin.database().ref(`/Applications/${applicationId}`);
        return database.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
        var nameId= snapshot.child("dogId").val();
        console.log('status',  snapshot.child('nameId').val());
        console.log('status',  snapshot.child('appWith').val());
        var userDatabase = admin.database().ref(`/users/TopUsers/${recieverId}/token`)
        return userDatabase.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
        var token = snapshot.val();
        console.log('status',  snapshot.val());
        var nameDatabase = admin.database().ref(`/names/${nameId}/name`)
        return nameDatabase.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
        var Name= snapshot.val();
        const message = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Application Recieved',
                body: 'Somebody has put an application in for '+Name,
                icon: "default"
            },
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,message).then((response) => {
            return console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        }).catch((error) => {
             return console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
        });
        });
        });
    });
```

Which works, however, i get a warning that says

```
  38:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
  42:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
  51:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
  51:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
```

which talks about nesting promises and looks at the return lines for each area.  My issue is that i can't seem to get my head around how i would un-nest the returns and get the same working result.

I'd appreciate any guidance anyone has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of chaining a `promise.then()` call within a callback, just return the `promise` and chain the `.then()` at the outer level of the chain.

As you have some variables that need to available in the next `then` callback (like `nameId`) you could use `Promise.all` to pass an array to the next callback in the chain, and include such variables in it:

```
exports.NotifyNewApplication = functions.database
    .ref(`/Applications/{applicationId}/appWith`)
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        var applicationId = context.params.applicationId; 
        console.log('status',  applicationId); 
        var recieverId = snapshot.val();
        var database = admin.database().ref(`/Applications/${applicationId}`);
        return database.once('value')
            .then(snapshot=>{
                var nameId= snapshot.child("dogId").val();
                console.log('status',  snapshot.child('nameId').val());
                console.log('status',  snapshot.child('appWith').val());
                var userDatabase = admin.database().ref(`/users/TopUsers/${recieverId}/token`)
                return Promise.all([nameId, userDatabase.once('value')]);
            }).then(([nameId, snapshot])=>{
                var token = snapshot.val();
                console.log('status',  snapshot.val());
                var nameDatabase = admin.database().ref(`/names/${nameId}/name`)
                return Promise.all([token, nameDatabase.once('value')]);
            }).then(([token, snapshot])=>{
                var Name= snapshot.val();
                const message = {
                    notification: {
                        title: 'Application Recieved',
                        body: 'Somebody has put an application in for '+Name,
                        icon: "default"
                    },
                };
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,message);
            }).then((response) => {
                return console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                return console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            });
```

Comment: So i'm getting  a type error with this at line 34:

TypeError: functions.database.ref(...).onCreate(...).then is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:34:8)

I tried removing the }) after: return.database.once('value') (the first return) and it gives me a nameId is not defined error so i guess what i'm asking is how do i pass the nameId to the next .then() statement?

Comment: I see. I had assumed `onCreate` returned a promise. So then your chain starts at the first `then`. To make variables available in the next callback in the chain, use  `Promise.all`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for this, so i'm getting a type error at snapshot.val(); saying it cannot read property of .val (at(nameId, Snapshot)) ...can i retrieve the snapshot in the same way if it's passed as an argument?

Comment: Hold on, there is a mistake. The argument should be an array. Let me correct that ... Corrected. Notice the added square brackets in some of the parameter lists.

Comment: So i added the brackets on the .then parameter list but i'm still getting .val() is not a function? do i need to call .once('value') before the promise and set it too the variable?

Comment: Sorry, the argument of `Promise.all` also needs to be an array: add brackets there too.

Comment: Brill, all works and i learnt a fair bit there...thanks for your time.